# How do you prevent over complicated solutions or designs?

Tags: complexity-theory, analysis

Many times we find ourselves working on a problem, only to figure out the solution being created is far more complex than the problem requires.  Are there controls, best practices, techniques, etc that help you control over complication in your workplace?

Comment: Looking at the first answer, I don't think this should be a community wiki. Great Q, great A.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Getting someone new to look at it.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, designing for an overly general case tends to breed too much complexity.

Engineering culture encourages designs that make fewer assumptions about the environment; this is usually a good thing, but some people take it too far.  For example, it *might* be nice if your car design doesn't assume a specific gravitational pull, nobody is actually going to drive your car on the moon, and if they did, it wouldn't work, because there is no oxygen to make the fuel burn.

The difficult part is that the guy who is developed the "works-on-any-planet" design is often regarded as clever, so you may have to work harder to argue that his design is *too* clever.

Understanding trade-offs, so you can make the decision between good assumptions and bad assumptions, will go a long way into avoiding a needlessly complicated design.

Answer (score 7):

If its too hard to test, your design is too complicated.  That's the first metric I use.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas to get design more simpler:

- read some programming books and articles, and then **apply** them in your work and write code
- read lots of code (good and bad) written by other people (like Open Source projects) and  learn to see what works and what does not
- build safety nets (unit tests) to enable experimentations with your code
- use version control to enable rollback, if those experimentations take wrong turn
- [TDD (test driven development)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development) and [BDD (behaviour driven development)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_driven_development)
- change your attitude, ask how you can make it so, that **"it simply works"** (convention over configuration could help there; or ask how Apple would do it)
- practice (like jazz players -- jam with code, try [Code Kata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/))
- write same code multiple times, with different languages and after some time has passed
- learn new languages with new concepts (if you use static language, learn dynamic one; if you use procedural language, learn functional one; ...) [one language per year is about right]
- ask someone to review you code and actively ask how you can make your code simpler and more elegant (**and then make it**)
- get years under your belt by doing above things (time helps active mind)

Answer (score 2):

I create a design etc., and then I look at it and try and remove (agressively) everything that doesn't seem to be needed.  If it turns out I need it later when I am polishing the design I add it back in.  I do this over several iterations, refining as I go along.

Answer (score 2):

Read "Working Effectively With Legacy Code" by Michael C. Feathers.

The point is, if you have code that works, and you need to change the design, nothing works better than making your code unit testable, and breaking your code into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Using Test Driven Development and following Robert C. Martin's [Three Rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd):

1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
3. You are not allowed to write any more production code than is sufficient to pass the one failing unit test.

In this way you are not likely to get much code that you don't need.  You will always be focused on making one important thing work and won't ever get too far ahead of yourself in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

**Test first** may help here, but it is not suitable for all situation. And it's not a panacea anyway.

**Start small** is another great idea. Do you really need to stuff all 10 design patterns into this thing? Try first to do it "stupid way". Doesn't quite cut it? Okay, do it "slightly less stupid way". Etc.

**Get it reviewed**. As someone else wrote, two pairs of eyes are better. Even better are two brains. Your mate may just see a room for simplification, or a problematic area you thought was fine just because you spend many hours hacking it.

**Use lean language.** Languages such as Java, or sometimes C++ sometimes seem to encourage nasty, convoluted solutions. Simple things tend to span over multiple lines of code, and you just need to use 3 external libraries and a big framework to manage it all. Consider using Python, Ruby, etc. - if not for your project, then for some private use. It can **change your mindset** to favor simplicity, and to be assured that simplicity is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the amount of data you're working with by serialising the task into a series of smaller tasks. Most people can only hold half a dozen (plus or minus) conditions in their head while coding, so make that the unit of implementation. Design for all the tasks you need to accomplish, but then ruthlessly hack the design so that you never have to play with more than half a dozen paths though the module.

This follows from Bendazo's post - simplify until it becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is inevitable once you have been a programmer that this will happen. If you seriously have unestimated the effort or hit a problem where your solution just doesn't work then stop coding and get talking to your project manager. I always like to take the solutions with me to the meeting, problem is A, you can do x which will take 3 days or we can try y which will take 6 days. Don't make the choice yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- Talk to other programmers every step of the way.  The more eyes there are on the design, the more likely an overcomplicated aspect is revealed early, before it becomes too ossified in the codebase.
- Constantly ask yourself how you will use whatever you are currently working on.  If the answer is that you're not sure, stop to rethink what you're doing.
- I've found it useful to jot down thoughts about how to potentially simplify something I'm currently working on.  That way, once I actually have it working, it's easier to go back and refactor or redo as necessary instead of messing with something that's not even functional yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a delicate balancing act: on the one hand you don't want something that takes too long to design and implement, on the other hand you don't want a hack that isn't complicated enough to deal with next week's problem, or even worse requires rewriting to adapt.

A couple of techniques I find helpful:

If something seems more complex than you would like then never sit down to implement it as soon as you have finished thinking about it.  Find something else to do for the rest of the day.  Numerous times I end up thinking of a different solution to an early part of the problem that removes a lot of the complexity later on.

In a similar vein have someone else you can bounce ideas off.  Make sure you can explain to them why the complexity is justified!

If you are adding complexity because you think it will be justified in the future then try to establish **when** in the future you will use it.  If you can't (realistically) imagine needing the complexity for a year or three then it probably isn't justifiable to pay for it now.

Answer (score 0):

I ask my customers *why* they need some feature.  I try and get to the bottom of their request and identify the problem they are experiencing.  This often lends itself to a simpler solution than I (or they) would think of.

Of course, if you know your clients' work habits and what problems they have to tackle, you can understand their problems much better from the get-go.  And if you "know them" know them, then you understand their speech better.  So, develop a close working relationship with your users.  It's step zero of engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Take time to name the concepts of the system well, and find names that are related, this makes the system more familiar. Don't be hesitant to rename concepts, the better the connection to the world you know, the better your brain can work with it.

Ask for opinions from people who get their kicks from clean, simple solutions.

Only implement concepts needed by the current project (a desire for future proofing or generic systems make your design bloated).